# Как удалить блок по атрибутам?

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти и удалить блок `<div aling="center">`

***html:***

```
...
   <td valign="top" class="td-for-content">
      <div aling="center">
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**С использованием jQuery**

```
$('.td-for-content [align="center"]').remove();
```

**На чистом JS с использованием querySelector**

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.td-for-content [align="center"]');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}
```

**На чистом JS oldschool**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('td-for-content');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var childrens = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var j = 0; j < childrens.length; j++){
        if(childrens[j].getAttribute('align') === 'center')
            childrens[j].parentNode.removeChild(childrens[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Стоит отметить, что `[align="center"]` - это [CSS-селектор](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors), который найдет все элементы у которых есть свойство `align="center"`, если нужно найти такие элементы только внутри блоков с `class="td-for-content"` тогда стоит применить селектор `.td-for-content > div[align="center"]`

Comment: @Sanya_Zol спасибо за уточнение, я был невнимателен. Исправил ответ, согласно вашему комментарию.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо найти все дивы с помощью var `alldiv=document.getElementsByTagName("div")`. Получишь объект-список, у которого есть свойства с числовыми именами (0,1,2...), которые ссылаются на найденные объекты div. Потом по этому объекту циклом пробегись `for(var i=0;i<alldiv.length;i=i+1)`. И у каждого из них возьми свойство `alldiv[i].align` и проверь, равняется ли оно строке `"center"`. Если равняется, то пусть выполнит `alldiv[i].parentNode.removeChild(alldiv[i])`.